# incorporate simple vimeo video request with jquery carousel

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I did a tutorial for a jquery carousel that scrolls a ul. At the moment the ul is hardcoded, but I want to use a simple call to vimeo api to bring in the videos for a certain user into the carousel.

I have uploaded my code here: http://www.welchcreative.co.uk/wp-content/infinitecarouselvimeo.zip

My problem is that I don't know where I should put the code for the simple vimeo call, because at the moment, I think that the problem is that the vimeo videos load after the jquery stuff because it uses window.onload rather than document ready and I can't seem to work out how to put the two and two together.

Ideally, 
1. the code loads the vimeo videos first and puts them in a ul wiht the correct classes. 
2. the carousel code then acts on the list above.
in that order.

I hope that isn't too vague. It's a pretty simple idea. I'm new to javascript and jquery.

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answer this question by saying that in the end I used the simple api php example to bring in the videos because it got round the problem of the window.onload overriding all the other event handlers (which I'm pretty sure was the problem).

Beware if you download the simple api php example and you are not really hot on php (as I'm not) that the short tags used in the example can stop it from working (if your set up doesn't have that enabled) so replace them with full php tags.

Cheers
Andy